# Set input value with Puppeteer-Sharp

Tags: c#, input, webautomation, puppeteer-sharp

I try to do this but I get an exception :

```
var text = "hello";
var input = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("input");
var button = await page.QuerySelectorAsync("button");
await input.EvaluateFunctionAsync($"e => e.value = '{text}'");
await button.EvaluateFunctionAsync("e => e.click()");
```

what is the correct way to set a value of an input with puppeteer sharp ?

Comment: What's the exception?

Answer (score 1):

using below,

```
using var page = browser.NewPageAsync().Result;

page.TypeAsync("input[name='elementname']", valuetobeset).Wait();
```